# GCP - what are mysql-access instances?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a Java application deployed to AppEngine Standard and connects to Cloud SQL via public IP. I was looking at VM instances dashboard and found a set of instances with the following naming pattern and these are alerting for high cpu utilization.

aet-uswest1-mysql--access-{abcd}

The description says "Anthos/GKE and Dataproc VMs are Google-managed and include built-in agents.". These are all e2-micro instances and I could not change the instance type. At first I thought these are the underlying AppEngine instances, but the AppEngine instances I use are F4 class, I think these instances are something else.

What are these instances and how are they used?

Here is the list I see under instances in VM instances dashboard. I can't ssh or manage these instances. (I have randomized the instance names and ip addresses)

Name,Agent,Active Alerts,System Events,Zone,Private IP,Size

aet-uswest1-mysql--access-abcd,Not applicable,0,0,us-west1-a,10.5.0.9,e2-micro

aet-uswest1-mysql--access-efgh,Not applicable,0,0,us-west1-a,10.5.0.12,e2-micro

aet-uswest1-mysql--access-ijkl,Not applicable,0,0,us-west1-b,10.5.0.3,e2-micro

aet-uswest1-mysql--access-mnop,Not applicable,0,0,us-west1-c,10.5.0.7,e2-micro

aet-uswest1-mysql--access-qrst,Not applicable,0,0,us-west1-b,10.5.0.5,e2-micro

aet-uswest1-mysql--access-uvwx,Not applicable,0,0,us-west1-b,10.5.0.10,e2-micro

aet-uswest1-mysql--access-yz01,Not applicable,0,0,us-west1-c,10.5.0.2,e2-micro

aet-uswest1-mysql--access-23df,Not applicable,0,0,us-west1-c,10.5.0.6,e2-micro

aet-uswest1-mysql--access-efef,Not applicable,0,0,us-west1-a,10.5.0.11,e2-micro

aet-uswest1-mysql--access-57sf,Not applicable,0,0,us-west1-b,10.5.0.13,e2-micro

Comment: Could you post TEXT result of a screenshot so we can see what you are observing?

Comment: hi, updated the question with the text version of the instance list.

Comment: Ask the owner of the application that gave you permission to wander around their data.  These are all instances of mysql in us-west1 availability zone and there are multiple sub zones involved to divide up the work  -a -b and -c.  Your hosting organization may have documentation available describing their services/methods of storing data.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding that AppEngine service was connected to Mysql via public network is incorrect. I found that these instances are related to VPC connector used by AppEngine standard to access MySQL service.